# How to retrieve details of second level tables in laravel relationships

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationship

I have 3 tables

```
bank(id, title), 

employee(id, name, bank_id), 

payroll(id, employee_id, salary).
```

Now I want to retrieve bank `title` of `employee_id` in `payroll` table.

I have set model relationships

```
class Bank extends Model
{
    public function employees()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Employee');
    }
}


class Employee extends Model
{
    public function bank()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Bank');
    }

    public function payrolls()
    {
       return $this->hasMany('App\Payroll');
    }
}

class Payroll extends Model
{
    public function employee()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Employee');
    }
 }
```

I have tried to retrieve using `$payroll->employee->bank->title.` But it did not help me

Comment: did you get any error when trying that?

Comment: yes "Trying to get property 'title' of non-object"

Comment: coud you ```dd($payroll->employee->bank->title).``` and show us what you get?

Comment: It shows the bank title when add dd($payroll->employee->bank->tilte)

Comment: This is really strange. Coud you try this code: ```$payroll->employee->first()->bank->first()->title``` this should work.

Comment: @RajaDurai, it seems to me that one, or some, of your `employee`, isn't referencing a `bank`.

Comment: Could you try this code: $payroll = Payroll::with('employee.bank')->get(); dd($payroll); and check result

Comment: @Carlos Afonso, Sorry it was my mistake. Yes, some employee ids are not referencing bank. Now I provided isset method to check reference value set or not.

Comment: Thank you all for your help.

Comment: @RajaDurai, great! Just make sure to close this post, you can answer it yourself explaining what was wrong and what you did to solve it, so next time someone goes through something similar they can find your solution ;)

Answer (score 0):

Sorry it was my mistake. some employee ids are not referencing bank. That was why I got error. 
I resolved the issue by using isset method to verify reference value set or not.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

try to change your code a little bit and try again:

```
 public function bank()
 {
        return $this->hasOne('App\Bank');
  }
```

Read Laravel Official Documentation
/** We can define the inverse of a hasOne relationship using the belongsTo method: **/